# how to normalizing the score in ElasticSearch and run custom sorting afterwards

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a filter query which varies in the boost and no of terms that are passed for filtering.

So basically the final score varies a lot. Ranging from 0.1923(something) to anywhere between 100-200.

I would like to sort the documents based on the score calculated by ES and a particular field value.

```
"script" : "_score + doc['my_numeric_field'].value"

# Where my_numeric_field value ranges from 1 -10
```

But if i don't normalize the score then, whenever default _score are high they will be the dominating factor in getting the final score. And whenever the _score is low, 'my_numeric_field' will be the dominating factor in sorting.

So how can i first normalize the _score value to some standard scale so i can have 70, 30 % on final score contributed by _score and my_numeric_field respectively.

One way to solve this would be if i know the max score i get in the sorting script. If i know that value then i can use that for normalizing the score of each document. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can do this within the script itself:

    `"script" : "_score * (30 / 100) + doc['my_numeric_field'].value * (70 / 100)"`. Isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: It wont help when the highest _score values is as low as say 0.123. In that case, 0.123 * 30/100 will not contribute to the sorting at all.

Comment: You can try to put it on a logarithmic scale. Since the Z-score will be needing two passes over the data.

Comment: @VikashSingh - Did you get what you were looking for ? I am kind of stuck in a similar problem. If you can share the solution, it would be great.

Comment: @RamandeepSingh we came up 1 simpler solution which was a quick hack, Run the query once, get the scores and use that score and pass it to the scoring function and run the same query again and normalise the score within the scoring function.

2nd solution which we used as final solution was writing a custom scoring function which limits max score (basically squash the max score using custom parameter for logistic function) and using that to normalise the final score.